# Travel between South Park and Canada

Tags: south-park

In South Park the characters seem to easily travel between Colorado and Canada.

Looking at a map Wyoming and Montana are in between Colorado  and Canada.

Did Matt and Trey know this or was this on purpose?

Comment: Considering the town of South Park is fictional, I would hope that everyone involved with the show would know some basic geography.  I'm not sure what you mean by "easily travel."  I haven't watched the show much over the last several years, so I don't know much of the travel times.

Comment: Yea, fictional is an explaination

Comment: Do they travel more easily than reality, or do they just cut out the travel because it's boring and has nothing to do with the story?

Comment: Yes, the travel is cut usually. In the game it implies that a quick walk in the woods will get you to the Canadian border.
(Shift + enter, not just enter......)

However in the episode "Royal Pudding" i remember Ike is seen riding the bus with many other Canadians back to Canada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***It is fiction and need not to be taken literally***. It only means that they travelled to some distant place.

Generally, they cut down the scenes through editing because there is nothing happens during the travel and boring to the audience.

Ike travels to Canada in a bus in S15 E03 [Royal Pudding](http://southpark.wikia.com/wiki/Royal_Pudding). And it is possible to go to Canada by road (because USA and Canada share a border). But that's nothing when compared to S02 E05 [Conjoined Fetus Lady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjoined_Fetus_Lady). In this episode, they go to China in a school bus.

If we look at the world map, it is practically impossible to go to China from  Washington D.C in a bus. They must travel in a plane or a ship which they never did.

[image: Word Map showing USA and China]

So, Travel from South Park to different countries need not to be taken literally. It is only meant to show that they travelled to that place.

Comment: Your profile pic makes this reply so much better